# How can I simplify this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, simplify

I have two table, first, I need do some searching to get the fk of another table like this...

```
SELECT `related_table_id` 
FROM `table_a` 
WHERE `users_id` = '14' 
  AND `user_data_status` = 'n' 
  AND `another_table_name` = 'table_b'
```

then, I have many related_table_id as an output... and I need to search the content, which is like %keyword%. 
 So, I need to query another SQL like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_b 
WHERE (`table_b_id`='218' OR  `table_b_id`='219' OR  `table_b_id`='225') 
  AND `content` LIKE '%keyword%'
```

The question is, when my db grown, and the table_b, may have a lot of data that can query from table_a, so, the sql statement will become very very long. Can I combine these two statement in one? Thank you/

Comment: Are 218, 219 and 225 the result from `related_table_id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a nested query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE `table_b_id` IN (SELECT `related_table_id` FROM `table_a` WHERE `users_id` = '14' AND `user_data_status` = 'n' AND `another_table_name` = 'table_b') AND `content` LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Comment: A nested query is a good alternative to a join if you don't need to select values from the subquery.

Comment: compare to the performance, nested query or inner join is a better?

Comment: @Tattat: Usually `INNER JOIN` is better (faster) than a nested query. But you can always test in your database and also compare the two query plans.

Comment: @ypercube on modern DBMS:s they are similar in performance and typically generate similar execution plans. Traditionally `INNER JOIN` has been faster, but modern query plan optimizers handle `IN SELECT` quite well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`INNER JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join) to "match" the rows of two or more tables.

```
SELECT table_b.* 
FROM table_b 
INNER JOIN table_a
ON table_a.related_table_id = table_b.table_b_id
WHERE table_a.users_id = '14' 
  AND table_a.user_data_status = 'n' 
  AND table_a.another_table_name = 'table_b'
  AND table_b.content LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Comment: You can add that `SELECT DISTINCT table_b.*` may be needed, so no duplicate records be shown.